# postgresql pdo very slow connect

Tags: php, performance, apache, postgresql, pdo

We are facing performance issue with our web server. We are using an apache server (2.4.4) with php 5.4.14 (it's a uniserver package) and a postgresql database 9.2. It’s on a Windows system (can be XP, 7 or server…).

Problem is that requests answers from the web server are too slow; we have made some profiling and found that database connection is around **20 ms** (millisecond).
We are using PDO like this:

```
$this->mConnexion = new \PDO(“postgres: host=127.0.0.1;dbname=”, $pUsername,$pPassword,  array(\PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => false));
```

We have made some time profiling like this:

```
echo "Connecting to db <br>";$time_start = microtime();

  $this->mConnexion = new \PDO(… 

$time_end = microtime();$time = $time_end - $time_start;

echo "Connecting to db done in $time sec<br>";
```

We have made a test with ATTR_PERSISTENT to true and we came up with a connection time much faster. Code reports connection time  **= 2. E-5  second** (whereas it’s **0.020 s** with persistent to false).

**Is 20 ms a normal value (and we have to move to persistent connection)  ?**

we have also made a test with mysql, connection time for non persistent connection is around 2 ms.

We have these options set in postgresql configuration file :

```
listen_addresses = '*'      
port = 5432   
max_connections = 100        
SSL = off   
shared_buffers = 32MB
```

**EDIT**

We do not use permanent (yet) because there are some drawbacks, if the script fail connection will be in a bad state (so we will have to manage these cases, and it’s what we will have to do…).  I would like to have more points of view concerning this database connection time before directly switching to persistent connection.

To answer Daniel Vérité question, SSL is off (I already checked this option from my previous search about the subject).

@Daniel : i have tested on a intel core 2 Extreme  CPU X9100 @ 3.06Ghz 4Gb RAM

Comment: Using persistent connections is a good idea, and usually has no drawbacks. I'd switch to that permanently, tbh - do you have any reason for not wanting to?

Comment: 20ms is indeed slow, but what's the CPU of the server? Also make sure SSL is off in postgresql.conf. Connection establishing may easily be 5x slower with SSL on.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I have updated the post. halfer, do you use register_shutdown_function to clean connection ?

Comment: The usual recommendation is to use [pgBouncer](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PgBouncer) rather than the built-in persistent connections of php. In a recent test I timed 2200 conn./sec with pgbouncer on linux in session mode to localhost on a Xeon E3-1230@3.2Ghz (a cheap server nowadays), vs 330/s without pgbouncer.

Comment: @Daniel i have edited to give the machine configuration

Comment: Try to profile with Wireshark (and try to do this from php on a different host), to be sure about who is doing it wrong: PHP, Apache or Postgres. (or maybe Windows)

Answer (score 1):

Try using unix domain socket by leaving host empty. It's a little bit faster.